# fullCalendar updateEvent 'completed' re-render event not all events

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar, qtip, qtip2

I currently have my events being pulled into my calendar dynamically. 
Then when I mouse-over the event it pops-up with a qTip (jquery plugin) to show a pop-up dialog.

I currently have a 'link' that is to 'complete' an item on the calendar, and i'm using this javascript to pull in my information from the link.

```
// Update event to be complete
        $('.updateEvent').live('click', function() {
            var goTo     = $(this).attr('href');
            var eventId1 = $(this).attr('rel');
            var eventId2 = eventId1.split("-");
            var eventId  = eventId2[1];

            $.ajax({
                  url: goTo,
                  dataType: 'html',
                  success: function (event, response) {
                        $("#"+eventId).fullCalendar('className', '.complete');
                        //$("#calendar").fullCalendar("refetchEvents");
                  },
                  error: function(response, data) {
                    alert("Oops... Looks like we're having some difficulties.");  
                  }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Is there a way to go about doing and update to the event "className"->".complete"
I know i'm supposed to pull in the actual 'event' but i'm un-sure how to do that with the jQuery qTip functionality.

I hope this makes sense, and if there is any direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
// Update event to be complete
        $('.updateEvent').live('click', function() {
            var goTo     = $(this).attr('href');
            var eventId1 = $(this).attr('rel');
            var eventId2 = eventId1.split("-");
            var eventId  = eventId2[1];

            $.ajax({
                  url: goTo,
                  dataType: 'html',
                  success: function (event, response) {

                      var eventNew = $("#calendar").fullCalendar("clientEvents", eventId);
                      console.log(eventNew);

                  },
                  error: function(response, data) {
                    alert("Oops... Looks like we're having some difficulties.");  
                  }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

When I write to the console.log(eventNew); it returns as NULL. and I know that the eventId is responding with an actual eventId, such as (17836).

Any other thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

My FULL JS Script on this page:
http://jsfiddle.net/ah73B/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to fetch a handle to the event first, before changing the classname. Take a look at `.fullCalendar( 'clientEvents' [, idOrFilter ] )` method. If you know the eventId, you can pass that as a filter to this method. Then change the className.

Hope this helps. You could post the HTML of the  for the question to be more clear.

Comment: Hey, I was excited to see your response, but was not able to get any further... I updated my code and the rest of my JS. If you are able to take another look that would be awesome.